# how to pass items into a cart on a new webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

So for the past few days I've been struggling on how to pas information from my product page to an order form. I'm to the point where I can't figure out what to do with the coding that I've done to make the web pages.

This is all of my coding for three pages

Home page:

```css
body{
  background-color:#56A5EC;
}
div.banner{
  text-align:center;
  color:#ED9C55;
  font-size:45px;
  width:750px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
div.nav{
  font-size:25px;
  color:#56A5EC;
  background-color:#ED9C55;
  width:750px;
  height:30px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  top:3px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
div.main{
  position:relative;
  top:6px;
  width:750px;
  height:600px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:white;
}
div.footer{
  background-color:#ED9C55;
  font-size: 20px;
  height:180px;
  width:752px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  bottom:8px;
  z-index:1;
  color:white;
}
p.welcome{
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  font-size:25px;
  color:blac
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="banner">Welcome to Electro-Market</div>
  <div class="nav"><a href="lab07_product_page.html">Product page</a></div>
  <div class=""main>
    <p class="welcome">
      Welcome to my store where we sell electronic devices that you may enjoy. Here we are committed to satisfying your needs.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    If you need to contact about stock avaliablity please don't hesitate to call (918)999-0987.
  </div>
</div>
```

Product page:

```js
var products = [];
var url_string = document.location.search.substring(1,document.location.search.length);
if( url_string.length > 0 ) {
  var parameters = url_string.split('&');
  for(var x = 0 ; x < parameters.length ; x++ ) {
    products.push(parameters[x].split('='));
  }
  console.log(products);
} else {
  console.log("no parameters");
} 

window.onload = function( ) {
  var form = document.getElementById("order_form");
  form.onsubmit = function( ) {
    var controls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for( var x = 0 ; x < controls.length ; x++ ){
      if( controls[x].type == "checkbox" && controls[x].checked ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    alert("You must select one product at least");
    return false;
  }


}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#56A5EC;
}
```

```html
<form action="lab07_order_form.html" method="get" id="order_form">
  <h2>Lenovo Computer - $650.00</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product1" value="" id="Product1"/>
    <label for="product-1"><img src="Lenovo-pc.jpg" alt="Computer" style="width:225px;height:200px;"> Thi computer has many features built into it such as Intel i5 core processor 8GB ram and 1 TB of memory.</label>
  </div>

  <h2>Nintendo 64 - $50.00</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product2" value="" id="Product2"/>
    <label for="product-2"><img src="Nintendo-64.jpg" alt="Nintendo" style="width:225px;height:200px;"> A console from the 90's that many kids loved to play at a friends house and an all around family activity. Though cartridges are sold separately and come in serveral different games.</label>
  </div>

  <h2>Playstation 2 - $150.00</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product3" value="" id="Product3"/>
    <label for="product-3"><img src="playstation.jpg" alt="ps2" style="width:225px;height:200px;"> The Playstation 2 is a more modern console that is one of our highly anticipated consoles.</label>
  </div>

  <h2>Xbox - $125.00</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Product4" value="" id="Product4"/>
    <label for="product-4"><img src="xbox.jpg" alt="xbox" style="width:225px;height:200px;">Xbox is made by microsoft and has one of the most iconic games ever played Halo and are in limited supply</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase item's"/>
  </div>
</form>

<form action="lab_07.html" method="get" id="lab_07">
  <input type="submit" value="Back"/>
</form>
```

Form page:

```js
var ids = ['first_name', 'last_name','street_address','city','state','zip', 'Billing_address', 'Billing_city', 'Billing_state', 'Billing_zip', 'Card_type', 'Card_number', 'Card_date'];


 function validate( ){
  var errors = new Array();

  for(var x = 0 ; x <document.forms[0].elements.length ; x++ ) {
   if(document.forms[0].elements[ x ].type == "text"){
    if(document.forms[0].elements[ x ].value == ""){
     errors.push("The " + document.forms[0].elements[x].name + " field cannot be blank\n");
     document.forms[0].elements[x].className = "in_error";
    } else {
     document.forms[0].elements[x].className = "no_error";
    }
   }

   if( document.forms[0].elements[x].type == "select-one"){
    if(document.forms[0].elements[x].selectIndex == 0){
     errors.push("The " + document.forms[0].elements[x].name + " field cannot be blank\n");
     document.forms[0].elements[x].className = "in_error";
    } else {
     document.forms[0].elements[x].className = "no_error";
    }
   }
  }

  if(errors.length == 0 ){
   return true;
  } else {
   clear_errors( );
   show_errors( errors );

   return false;
  }
 }
 
 var products = [];
      var url_string = document.location.search.substring(1,document.location.search.length);
      if( url_string.length > 0 ) {
        var parameters = url_string.split('&');
        for(var x = 0 ; x < parameters.length ; x++ ) {
          products.push(parameters[x].split('='));
        }
        console.log(products);
      } else {
        console.log("no parameters");
      }
 
 function FillBilling(z){
  if(z.billingtoo.checked == true) {
   z.Billing_address.value = z.street_address.value;
   z.Billing_city.value = z.city.value;
   z.Billing_state.value = z.state.value;
   z.Billing_zip.value = z.zip.value;
  }
   if(z.billingtoo.checked == false){
    z.Billing_address.value = '';
    z.Billing_city.value = '';
    z.Billing_state.value = '';
    z.Billing_zip.value = '';
  }
 }

 function clear_errors(){
  var div = document.getElementById( "errors" );
  while(div.hasChildNodes()){
   div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
  }
 }

 function show_errors( errors ) {
  var div = document.getElementById( "errors" );
  for( var x = 0 ; x < errors.length ; x++ ) {
   var error = document.createTextNode( errors[ x ]);
   var p = document.createElement( "p" );
   p.appendChild(error);
   div.appendChild(p);
  }
 }

 window.onload = function() {
  document.forms[ 0 ].onsubmit = validate;
  
  for( var x = 0 ; x < ids.length ; x++ ) {
        var element = document.getElementById(ids[x]);
  element.onfocus = function(){
   console.log(this.id + " has been focused");
   this.className = "element_focused";
   document.getElementById(this.id + "_label").className = "element_focused";
  }
  
  element.onblur = function( ) {
          console.log(this.id + " has been blurred");
          this.className = "";
          document.getElementById(this.id + "_label").className = "";
        }
 }
 
  var products_div = document.getElementById("products");
        var order_form = document.getElementById("order_form");

        for( var x = 0 ; x < products.length ; x++ ) {
          //create colored background div's
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.style.backgroundColor = products[x][1];
          products_div.appendChild(div);

          //create form fields
          var input = document.createElement("input");
          input.type = "hidden";
          input.name = products[x][0];
          input.value = products[x][1];
          order_form.appendChild(input);
        }
 }
```

```css
#errors {
  color: #F00;
}

.in_error{
  background-color: #F00;
}

.no_error{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

input.element_focused, select.element_focused {
  border: 5px solid #F00;
}

label.element_focused {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<h1>Products</h1>
<div id="products"></div>

<div id="errors"></div>

<form method="get" action="https://suchnull.com/examples/echo">

  <p>
    <label for="first_name" id="first_name_label">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first name" value="" id="first_name"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="last_name" id="last_name_label">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last name" value="" id="last_name"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="street_address" id="street_address_label">Shipping Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="street address" value="" id="street_address"/>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="FillBilling(this.form)" name="billingtoo"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="city" id="city_label">Shipping City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" value="" id="city"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="state" id="state_label">Shipping State:</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" value="" id="state"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="zip" id="zip_label">Shipping Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" value="" id="zip"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Billing_address" id="Billing_address_label">Billing address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Billing address" value="" id="Billing_address"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Billing_city" id="Billing_city_label">Billing City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Billing city" value="" id="Billing_city"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Billing_state" id="Billing_state_label">Billing State:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Billing state" value="" id="Billing_state"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Billing_zip" id="Billing_zip_label">Billing Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Billing zip" value="" id="Billing_zip"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Card_type" id="Card_type_label">Credit Card Type:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Card type" value="" id="Card_type"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Card_number" id="Card_number_label">Credit Card Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Card number" value="" id="Card_number"/>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="Card_date" id="Card_date_label">Credit Card Expiration Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Card date" value="" id="Card_date"/>
  </p>

  <p>
  <form method="get" action="https://suchnull.com/examples/echo">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check"  /> I've completed the information
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="if(!this.form.checkbox.checked){alert('You must agree to the terms first.');return false}"  />
  </form>

  </p>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me understand how to transfer the image of the product, price, and name because I'm completely lost on how to do this.

Comment: where you want to transfer the image ???

Comment: Ideally I'd like to have the image, product name, and price right above the form and below the <h1>Products on the form page

Comment: Do you have an url where you have deployed the code?like github ,jsfiddle or something like that?

Comment: um no but I can work on that.

Comment: ok because i think you are fetching the product details from the url when you navigate to the form page right ?so it would be easier to test using an url

Comment: all i know from the the product page I need to send one of the selected items to the next page. I've established that an item needs to be selected before it can continue to the form page. but I just don't know how to code it to carry over the images, names, and prices.

Comment: https://github.com/Picklesberry/wolf-den heres the files for anyone willing to help

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp